# jQuery selector select node without child node

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

How can I select all `.sp_container` that have no childs with class `portlet`

This doesn't work : `div.sp_container[> div.portlet]`

```
<div class='sp_container' style=''>

<div class='portlet' style='background:#ff9900;padding:20px;'>
    <div class='sp_container' >
    </div>
</div>

<div class='portlet' style='background:#ff11aa;padding:20px;'>
    <div class='sp_container' >
    </div>
</div>

<div class='portlet' style='background:#336699;padding:20px;'>
    <div class='sp_container' >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be a little more specific if you want an answer.

Comment: Can you be more clear? You want to select all `sp_container` that don't have a `portlet` parent? is that it>

Comment: i want get all elements with class_name sp_container there no contains a element with class_name portlet.

Comment: Still don't get it... What do you mean by `there no contains`

Comment: sorry, my english is veryy terrible. I want to get all elements .sp_container that contain no element .portlet as a child

Comment: @user1291558 see my answer. It should do the trick; thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, you could use `filter()`. This should work.

```
$('.sp_container').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children('.portlet').length === 0;
});
```

Comment: +1 This helped me. I just replaced `children` with `find` since I was looking for children that where nested a bit deeper :)

Answer (score 0):

This will return the all `sp_container` elements without any children, which is what I think you're looking for.

```
var myElems = [];

$(".sp_container").each(function() {
    if($(this).children() == undefined) {
        myElems.push(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: `<div id='1' class='sp_container' style=''>

<div id='2' class='portlet' style='background:#ff9900;padding:20px;'>
    <div  id='3' class='sp_container' >
    </div>
</div>

<div id='4' class='portlet' style='background:#ff11aa;padding:20px;'>
    <div id='5' class='sp_container' >
    </div>
</div>

<div id='6' class='portlet' style='background:#336699;padding:20px;'>
    <div id='7' class='sp_container' >
    </div>
</div>`


I need the Element with id 3,5,7 but not element with id 1.

id 1 contains the child .portlet in the first level